# bootstrap doesn't maintain grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-5

it's a pretty basic bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4" id="home_form">
    <%= render "supporters/form" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8" id="home_list" id="home_list">
    <%= render 'supporters/show_supporters' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

but i've got this, which previously placed a form error directly above the form like a regular rendered rails form with an error.

```
$(build_error).insertBefore( "#home_form" );
```

but now it puts it to the left of, and with the same height as #home_form, and throws #home_list underneath both.

build_error:

```
<% if @supporter.save %>
        $("#home_list").html("<%= j render 'show_supporters' %>")
        $("home_form").html("<%= j render 'form' %>")
    <% else %>
        $("#home_form").html("<%= j render 'form', supporter: @supporter %>") 
        $('#build_error').remove();
        <% if @supporter.errors.any? %>
          var build_error = "<div class='alert alert-danger' id='build_error'>";
          build_error += "You've got <%= pluralize(@supporter.errors.count, 'error') %>.";
          build_error +=   "<ul id='error_explanation'>";
          <% @supporter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <% if msg === "Ip has already been taken" %>
                <% msg = "You've already posted your support.   Thanks!" %>
            <% end %>
            build_error += "<li><%= j msg %></li>";
          <% end %>
          build_error +=   "</ul>";
          build_error += "</div>";
          $(build_error).insertBefore( "#home_form" );
        <% end %>           
    <% end %>
```

edit:

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="home_form">
      <%= render "supporters/form" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8" id="home_list" id="home_list">
    <%= render 'supporters/show_supporters' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is `build_error`?

Comment: updated.   ... i'm a n00b, just throwing around things i pick up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `build_error` is inserted before `#home_form`, it becomes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class='alert alert-danger' id='build_error'>...</div>

  <div class="col-md-4" id="home_form">
    <%= render "supporters/form" %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8" id="home_list" id="home_list">
    <%= render 'supporters/show_supporters' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you don't have any bootstrap `.col-` class on that element, so the `.row` negative margin is messing up your styles.

So, one solution is to add some `.col-` class on that element:

```
var build_error = "<div class='alert alert-danger col-md-12' id='build_error'>";
```

Comment: awesome.  i one upped it and threw the form in an addition div inside the previous home_form div so that it remained inside the form div, as per the edit in original question.  so simple, much appreciated!

Comment: check this for further fun!   [uploaded the site and it fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299287/site-fails-when-uploaded-to-heroku)